# Quasar framework electron mode how to open a child window and display a VUE 3 route

Tags: electron, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am working on an electron app using the Quasar framework and Vue 3. I am to a point where i want to open a child window and in that child window load a vue 3 route to display my page but what I have is not working so reaching out for some help.

I have a preload script and in it I have a call to the ipc system it is as follows

```
details: (payload: any) => ipcRenderer.invoke('details', payload),
```

then in my electron-main.ts I have the following

```
ipcMain.handle('details', async (event, payload) => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({ 
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: false,
        }
    });
    win.loadURL(`${process.env.APP_URL}/details`);
});
```

but this is not working nothing is coming up. I am lost here at this point I am not sure how to open a child window using the preload script I do have @electron/remote installed and was trying to open the window in my preload script as well but again no luck there.

So can anyone point me in the right direction? Or point me to some documentation to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this after trying the same.
I am calling it from the preload and not using the icprenderer function but I think you are just missing

```
win.show()
```

at the end